Знаки препинания прямая речь внутри слов автора, мысли
Вместо того чтобы думать: «Кто виноват?», я думаю: «Что делать?".
Правильно ли здесь стоят двоеточия?

И с двоеточим красиво, и без них можно обойтись, говорит мой редакторский опыт.
